# Are line integral function of a function differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I was reading Tom Apostol calculus volume 2 and came across theorem 10.4 FIRST FUNDAMENTAL THEOREM FOR LINE INTEGRALS (page 338)

> The theorem roughly stated: $\vec f$ be a vector field that is continuous on an open connected set S in $R^n$ and assume that the line integral of  $\vec f$ is independent of path in S .   $\vec a$ be  a fixed point of S and define a scalar field $\phi$ on S by the equation $$\phi(\vec x)=\int_{\vec a}^\vec x\vec f.d\vec \alpha$$
>   Where $\vec\alpha$ is any piecewise smooth path in S joining $\vec a $ and $\vec x $.Then the gradient of $\phi$ exists and is equal to $\vec f $.

My question is in the proof it was proved that the $D_t \phi(\vec x)=f_t$
for all k in {1,2,3,4,5,....,n}, Whereas the theorem states **gradient should exist that is the function $\phi(\vec x)$ should be differentiable, if so how to PROVE IT**?

Comment: You mean to say $D_k \phi(\vec x)=f_k,$ not $D_t$  This is the definition of $\nabla\phi=f$  I don't understand your question.

Comment: sorry typing error

Comment: now is my question okay?

Comment: @MarkS.: It's not quite that simple for multivariate functions, since being differentiable is a stronger condition than just having partial derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first partial derivatives exist and are equal to $f_k$, and each $f_k$ is continuous (by assumption), then $\phi$ is of class $C^1$, hence (by a well-known basic theorem) differentiable.

Comment: Oh yes ! thank you very much